# How to provide Authorization & Authentication using Asp.net, C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a asp.net application in c#.

I have to provide page authorization to specific user/usergroup.

[image]

I have created two tables in database:
1) pagename 2)permissions[Insert, update, view, delete]

but i'm unable to match the tables and its permissions assigning...

can any one please help me, 
how to created its tables in database and how to do coding.

Please help me.

Comment: Seems like you know nothing :P

Comment: Check my answer.. Hope it will solve your problem...

Answer (score 0):

You can do as below explanation.

> Configure Access to a Specific File and Folder, Set up forms-based
>   authentication.

Request any page in your application to be redirected to Logon.aspx automatically.

In the `Web.config` file, type or paste the following code.

This code grants all users access to the `Default1.aspx` page and the `Subdir1 folder`.

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <authentication mode="Forms" >
            <forms loginUrl="login.aspx" name=".ASPNETAUTH" protection="None" path="/" timeout="20" >
            </forms>
        </authentication>
<!-- This section denies access to all files in this application except for those that you have not explicitly specified by using another setting. -->
        <authorization>
            <deny users="?" /> 
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
<!-- This section gives the unauthenticated user access to the Default1.aspx page only. It is located in the same folder as this configuration file. -->
        <location path="default1.aspx">
        <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users ="*" />
        </authorization>
        </system.web>
        </location>
<!-- This section gives the unauthenticated user access to all of the files that are stored in the Subdir1 folder.  -->
        <location path="subdir1">
        <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users ="*" />
        </authorization>
        </system.web>
        </location>
</configuration>
```

Users can open the Default1.aspx file or any other file saved in the Subdir1 folder in your application. They will not be redirected automatically to the Logon.aspx file for authentication.

Repeat configuration Step to identify any other pages or folders for which you want to permit access by unauthenticated users.

For more Reference check Microsoft support page - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/301240

And also you can check http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/authorization

After you have to do coding on login page for reference check this -> http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13872/Form-authentication-and-authorization-in-ASP-NET

Comment: Thanks for help,
I have gone with above information, but the thing is...
I have to save the changes based on users..
some time may one of the user can insert or not..

Comment: there is no matter n number of users can manage by this authorization and authentication.

Comment: I think you don't know this ASP.NET & C# coding so there is no meaning to explain you complete coding..

Comment: Yes, you are right.. can u plz ping any ref or sample code. Please.

Comment: check those links which i have provided in answer.. u will get reference coding..